SaveAsTable with schemaName.TableName
We have unity catalog on the cluster and I have delta files in a location, delta_table_path = "/mnt/delta/sales/Products"
I want to create my delta table with sales as the schema and tablename as Products like this, sales.Products.I have created sales schema.
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("sales.Products")

When I used the above statement, it's giving me error that there is no database called sales. How can I save the table under the schema?

I have tried the following approach:
from pyspark.sql.types import *
dept_data = [
    (1, "HR", 101),
    (2, "Finance", 102),
    (3, "IT", 103),
    (4, "Marketing", 104),
    (5, "Sales", 105)
]
dept_schema = StructType([
    StructField("dept_id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("dept_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("manager_id", IntegerType(), True)
])
dept_df = spark.createDataFrame(dept_data, schema=dept_schema)
dept_df.show()

+-------+---------+----------+
|dept_id|dept_name|manager_id|
+-------+---------+----------+
|      1|       HR|       101|
|      2|  Finance|       102|
|      3|       IT|       103|
|      4|Marketing|       104|
|      5|    Sales|       105|
+-------+---------+----------+

I have saved the data in delta format to the following path.
Next, save the department DataFrame as a table with schema merging enabled.
Fresh_path = "/FileStore/tables/new01"
dept_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(Fresh_path)
dept_df.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("spark_catalog.default.DEPARTMENT1")

Results:

select * from spark_catalog.default.DEPARTMENT1

dept_id dept_name   manager_id
4   Marketing   104
2   Finance 102
5   Sales   105
3   IT  103
1   HR  101

Reference:
Create your first table and grant privileges in Unity Catalog
